# Raspberry pi pip installation

Tags: python, linux, opencv, pip, raspbian

I am trying to install apriltag in my Raspberry Pi  3 with Raspbian Jessie OS using the command -> `pip install apriltag`. It is returning an error:

```
Command "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-4ic0awdt/apriltag/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');
f.close();
exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-4a_4lmt1/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/include/site/python3.4/apriltag"
failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-4ic0awdt/apriltag/
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: the pip package is unofficial, try following the instructions at https://github.com/swatbotics/apriltag

Comment: You did not provide the code causing the error. Please show the relevant code and state the exact error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade pip.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

If that does not work reinstall pip.

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip && sudo apt-get install python-pip
```